# If, ElseIf, OrElse syntax in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, syntax

I am having some confusion with some VB syntax. I have this if/else/if/elseif statement I have in VB. It works, but looking around it seems like this can be cleaned up. I am new to VB coming from a C# background and I am not quite sure how to properly tweak it to clean it up. Below is my code:

```
                If taskPath = "\" Then
                    taskPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(TempFilePath)
                Else
                    If InStr(taskPath, "\\") = 1 Then
                    ElseIf InStr(taskPath, "\") = 1 Then
                        taskPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(TempFilePath), Mid(taskPath, 2, Len(taskPath) - 1))
                    End If
                End If
```

I would like to be able  to say:

```
If Foo then
   Bar
ElseIf Foo Then
    OrElse foo then
       bar
End If
```

Except everytime I try that type of Syntax I get errors.

I hope this makes sense, but if not, leave a comment and I will try to clarify

Comment: `OrElse` is equivalent to `||` in C#.  `Then` doesn't have an exact equivalent, but it's pretty close to the opening `{` of the block (in VB, there is no equivalent `}` for an `ElseIf` or `Else`, but `End If` is like a `}`).  If you get rid of the `Then` that immediately precedes the `OrElse` in your pseudocode you'll have valid code (modulo possibly needing a line continuation, there are still some forms in this neighborhood that need it).

Comment: That having been said, your pseudocode isn't the right way to convert the code you gave.  I think you want to invert the first condition and use `AndAlso` (equivalent to C# `&&`) if you're bound and determined to reconfigure the statement.  Why do you want to?  The trouble here shows the hazards involved, I think what you have is actually easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the syntax should be:

```
If Foo then
   Bar
ElseIf Foo OrElse foo then
   bar
End If
```

With your actual code, this becomes:

```
If taskPath = "\" Then
   taskPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(TempFilePath)
ElseIf InStr(taskPath, "\\") = 1 OrElse InStr(taskPath, "\") = 1 Then
   taskPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(TempFilePath), d(taskPath, 2, Len(taskPath) - 1))
End If
```

Comment: So the only difference that can be made to clean it up is to consolidate the second IF and ElseIf? No need for an OrElse? Edit: I see the OrElse now.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... there is an OrElse, you just do it as a single line.

Comment: Per my comment on the question, I don't think your update is actually a correct translation of the original.  The sense of the first conditional has been reversed (it was no action if `= 1` thus the correct condition for taking action is `<> 1`) and since the second conditional was originally an `Else` it should be combined with the negated condition using `AndAlso`.